# Decrypting string using OpenSSL works in terminal but not in PHP script

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to decrypt a file, I can decrypt it using OpenSSL in the terminal using the following string.

```
openssl -enc -d -aes-192-ecb -in file.crypt -out file -K 0123456789abcdef -iv 0
```

However, I want to decrypt this file in PHP. I have the following code:

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.crypt');
$key = 0123456789abcdef;
$data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, $key, $file, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

print_r($data);
```

Obviously I'm missing something as the PHP script is returning data, but not the plain-text.

I have tried using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 but with no luck. Please let me know if you can see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

---

I have successfully decrypted my file using the following:

```
$key = pack('H*', '0123456789abcdef'); //In >= PHP 5.4 you can use hex2bin() I think.
$data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $file, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

Comment: Does `$file` actually contain the encrypted contents of the file?

Comment: Can you show how you're encrypting the file, so that we can reproduce?

Comment: What if you try using 0 as the 5th parameter to mcrypt_decrypt? `mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, $key, $file, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 0);`

Comment: @Mike: the file.crypt is an encrypted sqlite database. Using 0 as the fifth parameter causes the mcrypt_decrypt function to return false.

Comment: @Drew: I am not encrypting the file, it's encrypted by an application which I don't have white-box access to.

Comment: @Epiphron according to [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html) the IV must be a string, so maybe try `"0"`.

Comment: @Epiphron and you misunderstood my first question. Does the PHP variable `$file` actually contain the contents of that file? I'm just trying to determine whether there was any sort of read error.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for your ideas. I have tried replacing the IV with 0 previously, apologies I forgot to mention it in my post (it returns false). Yes, the `$file` variable contains the correct data, I have just checked.

Comment: I don't see how that's even possible unless there is an error in the manual page for mcrypt_decrypt because `FALSE` is not one of the [possible return values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php#refsect1-function.mcrypt-decrypt-returnvalues).

Comment: @Mike, yes you're correct. It actually generates an error `mcrypt_decrypt - [internal], line ??`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrypting data with openssl commandline tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160788/decrypting-data-with-openssl-commandline-tool). The cited question uses `PHP`, `mcrypt` and `openssl` command line tool.

Comment: @noloader, thanks for the link. I've reviewed the linked question and it doesn't duplicate this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keys and IV in `openssl` are in hexadecimals (and therefore too short) and those in PHP are used as character values. Please specify 32, 48 or 64 hexadecimal digits for AES keys in openssl and the same value in 16, 24 or 32 bytes in PHP. The IV should always be 32 hex digits or 16 bytes as that is the block size of AES.

You should always use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` as the 128 in there is the block size - not the key size - of the algorithm, The `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192` and `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` algorithms do *not* implement AES.

Also, openssl defaults to PKCS#7 padding, check the `mcrypt_encrypt` comments section for implementation of PKCS padding for PHP - it does not provide it by default.

Comment: "The MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192 and MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 algorithms do not implement AES". +1. Lots of people don't realize that and interchange AES and Rijndael.

Comment: @owlstead Thank you very much! I modified my PHP code using your answers and I have successfully decrypted the file. I have edited my original question to include the changes.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please note that the 8 byte key is still short. It may be that the key is extended with `00` valued bytes - it certainly is with PHP mcrypt - but such keys are not strong enough for AES-128 keys (16 hex characters equals 8 bytes, or 64 bit, half of the keysize of AES-128).

Comment: @noloader The initial sample of `mcrypt_encrypt` used `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` among many other errors. So I filed a bug report and changed the official sample code :) A lot less questions about that now...

Answer (score 1):

> openssl -enc -d -aes-192-ecb -in file.crypt -out file -K 0123456789abcdef -iv 0

Specify your key in a keyfile with `-kfile`, and not on the command line with `-K`.

---

Maybe I'm reading the sources of `<openssl dir>/apps/enc.c` wrong, but it looks broke to me when using the `-K` option.

First, there is a declaration for hex encoded values from the command line (line 114):

```
char *hkey=NULL,*hiv=NULL,*hsalt = NULL;
```

Next, `hkey` is populated from the command line (line 265);

```
else if (strcmp(*argv,"-K") == 0)
{
    if (--argc < 1) goto bad;
    hkey= *(++argv);
}
```

Then, a few tests are performed. First, line 422:

```
if ((str == NULL) && (cipher != NULL) && (hkey == NULL))
{
    ...
    EVP_read_pw_string(...)
    ...
}
```

And then line 581:

```
if ((hkey != NULL) && !set_hex(hkey,key,sizeof key))
{
    BIO_printf(bio_err,"invalid hex key value\n");
    goto end;
}
```

Then nothing else is done with `hkey`.

---

Now, following the `kfile` option looks much more interesting:

```
else if (strcmp(*argv,"-kfile") == 0)
{
    static char buf[128];
    FILE *infile;
    char *file;
    /* lots of reading and parsing removed */
    ...
    str=buf;
}
```

After the key is assigned to `str`, something is done with it:

```
if (cipher != NULL)
{
    /* Note that str is NULL if a key was passed on the command
     * line, so we get no salt in that case. Is this a bug?
     */
    if (str != NULL)
    {
        /* Salt handling: if encrypting generate a salt and
         * write to output BIO. If decrypting read salt from
         * input BIO.
         */
        unsigned char *sptr;
        if(nosalt) sptr = NULL;
        else
        {
            if(enc) {
                if(hsalt) {
                    if(!set_hex(hsalt,salt,sizeof salt)) {
                        BIO_printf(bio_err, "invalid hex salt value\n");
                        goto end;
                    }
                } else if (RAND_pseudo_bytes(salt, sizeof salt) < 0)
                    goto end;
                ...
                EVP_BytesToKey(cipher,dgst,sptr,
                              (unsigned char *)str,
                              strlen(str),1,key,iv);
```

---

Here's a small debugging session with a [write watchpoint](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) on `key`. Its not written when using the `-K` option (though it is used in some `EVP_*` functions):

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1000071c0: file enc.c, line 106.
(gdb) watch key@16
Hardware watchpoint 3: {<data variable, no debug info>} 140735109990496 @ 16
(gdb) r -d -aes-192-ecb -in file.crypt -out file.txt -K 0123456789abcdef -iv 0
Starting program: .../openssl-1.0.1e/apps/enc.exe -d -aes-192-ecb -in file.crypt
-out apps.c -K 0123456789abcdef -iv 0

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=11, argv=0x7fff5fbff970) at enc.c:106
106         char *strbuf=NULL;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program exited normally.
```

---

Just bike shedding here: `aes-192-ecb` and `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB` is only secure if you don't reuse keys and the file is 16 bytes or less. As soon as you reuse the key or exceed 16 bytes, you loose PRP-security.